# libGDX without android dependancies

Tags: libgdx, android

I want to create a game that due to some assumptions doesn't make sense as a tablet game.

I already created some frame (controllers, autowiring, build scripts, etc.) that would help me later on, but since Slick2D, that I currently basing it on, is no longer really supported I am considering switching to libGDX while it still not time expensive.

My question is: is it possible to easily get rid of all of Android dependencies? GUI scaffold generator doesn't allow to do that and I would like to know is it just generator's issue or is the library itself tied to Android dependencies?

It's my main concern that would help me decide whether or not switch from Slick.

EDIT:

Basically when I use GUI generator to scaffold project it creates at least 3 Eclipse projects:

- core project,
- Android project - depending on core,
- desktop project - depending on Android.

While it shouldn't a be problem to merge them into 1 bigger project and remove virtually dead code, I want to know if there would be left some Android dependencies that I couldn't remove to make it still runnable on desktop.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, but... did you try porting your project over? That will be the best way to figure this out.

Comment: I already made one short attempt but was discouraged by the necessity to generate the android project (that I want to get rid of) and overall project layout. At that moment I was pretty busy so I couldn't spare more time to try to fix that... But I'll give it another shot hoping that I won't end up with several libraries that I neither need nor am able to remove. Perhaps I figure out why generated desktop project have to depend on Android one. Still, it would be useful if somebody explained why someone thought that such dependency is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: Besides that it is usually good idea to ask before doing something, since there's a chance that someone with more knowledge would warn me that it cannot be done the way I want to.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand. Google for "libgdx project setup." You'll still need an Android project, but the core game is in a simple Java project (not Android specific).

Comment: If that's the case I'll try to see how far I can go with the cleanup. If results will be pleasing I'd switch from Slick2D and write here what I had to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments -- I finally understand what you want.

TLDR: the summary of your question is encapsulated in the [libGDX project setup](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew) page.

Essentially, libGDX has you create one "core" project (which is a standard Java project). Within it, you have your main game code.

Beyond that, you have wrapper projects (one per platform); these only call the main startup code from the core application.

For example, if you want a standard Java (Desktop) app and an Android app, you would have these projects:

- Core game (standard Java)
- Desktop wrapper
- Android wrapper

It's pretty versatile; I understand there's an iOS wrapper project now, too.

Comment: Thanks! Information that there is no Android dependencies in simple desktop is very useful. I was bewildered by the assumption that Android project has to be created while it can be safely removed without any problems.

Comment: @maddening it's crazy to hear you say that, because libGDX was (and is) primarily for developing Android games; other platforms grew out of that. Still, I'm glad it's useful for you.